# jquery - How to put an array value into an animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem when trying to insert a random value from an array in an object animation, any idea how to solve this problem?

```
var modalExitDir = Array('top','right','bottom','left');
//random value from modalExitDir
var item = modalExitDir[Math.floor(Math.random()*modalExitDir.length)];

$('#modal-close-btn').click(function(){
    $('#jobs-modal').animate({
        item : -100 + '%',
        opacity : 0.5},
        500, function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way I can think of is using a `switch()` to check the `item` variable which should also appear inside the click function: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uuyrbj40/1/)**

```
var modalExitDir = Array('top','right','bottom','left');
//random value from modalExitDir

$('#modal-close-btn').click(function(){
    var item = modalExitDir[Math.floor(Math.random()*modalExitDir.length)];
    switch(item){
        case 'top':
            $('#jobs-modal').animate({top:'-100%'},500);
            break;
        case 'right':
            $('#jobs-modal').animate({left:'100%'},500);
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            $('#jobs-modal').animate({top:'100%'},500);
            break;
        case 'left':
            $('#jobs-modal').animate({left:'-100%'},500);
            break;
    }
    $('#jobs-modal').animate({
        opacity : 0.5},
        500, function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice! Works perfectly! Thanks a lot man! IF anybody want to see the example working: http://jsfiddle.net/g0utuxc7/1/

Comment: you're welcome, it's a really nice idea, the thing you did! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var modalExitDir = Array('top','right','bottom','left');
var item;

$('#modal-close-btn').click(function(){
 item= modalExitDir[Math.floor(Math.random()*modalExitDir.length)];
    $('#jobs-modal').animate({
        item : -100 + '%',
        opacity : 0.5},
        500, function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

Comment: Here ir what i'm trying to do(your code is implemented): http://jsfiddle.net/g0utuxc7/ , click in any "image" then it will open a modal, the problem is in cle close action, when close the direct to go should be random but it is nos working... Understand what i'm trying to say?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand (((